# How to fix connection not established on smtp mailtrap.io in centos

Tags: laravel, smtp, telnet

I have already set up my config in env for my mail server

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

It works fine in my local server. But when I test it on my production server, it doesn't work any more. 
I also tried modifying my iptables to allow the port connections

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Fri Feb 19 14:47:25 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [72:5432]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [53:7392]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1025 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

But to no good. It still says Connection not established whenever I try to send a test email.

Then I tried to telnet and it timeouts

```
[root@root laravel5]# telnet mailtrap.io 25
Trying 52.20.34.166...
telnet: connect to address 52.20.34.166: Connection timed out
Trying 52.22.93.185...
telnet: connect to address 52.22.93.185: Connection timed out
Trying 52.5.202.66...
telnet: connect to address 52.5.202.66: Connection timed out
```

What could cause this? Can anybody help me on this? Thank you sooo much.

Comment: A lot of hosts, isps, etc. block port 25. Have you tried port 465 or 2525?

Comment: yes i did use port 465 and 2525, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use port 2525 as all other *mailtrap.io* config codes suggest.

```
SMTP
Host: mailtrap.io or smtp.mailtrap.io (MX)
Port: 25 or 465 or 2525
```

Also try to add subdomain:

```
smtp.mailtrap.io
```

If it does not work, write to *support@mailtrap.io*

Answer (score 3):

I changed my config.port 2525 to 25 and it works

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=222222eferfeferfe
MAIL_PASSWORD=erferferferferfef
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: did not worked for me